# Sequelize: issue with "belongsToMany" (Many-to-many association)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, es6-class

I'm trying to make a Many-to-Many association in Sequelize (and `Postgres`) using the `belongsToMany` approach but I'm facing some issues. The scenario is really common and goes around three tables: `t_users` (model name `User`), `t_roles` (model name `Role` and their link table `t_user_role` (model name `UserRole`).

It's worth mentioning that all tables, the link table included, were previously created using [node-db-migrate](https://github.com/db-migrate/node-db-migrate) (I can provide the migration code if necessary).

Before explaining the issue, the files involved:

**User model**

```js
class User extends Sequelize.Model {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
}

const dbUser = {
  a_id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
  },
  a_date_created: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  a_first_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  a_last_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  a_email: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  a_password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  a_birthday: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  a_is_active: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    allowNull: false,
  },
};

User.init(dbUser, {
  sequelize: db, // db holds the sequelize connection instance
  modelName: 't_user',
  timestamps: false,
  tableName: 't_users',
});


User.associate = (models) => {
  User.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
    through: { model: UserRole, unique: false },
    as: 'roles',
    foreignKey: 'a_user',
    otherKey: 'a_role',
  });
};
```

**Role model**

```js
class Role extends Sequelize.Model {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
}

const dbRole = {
  a_id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
  },
  a_role: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
};

Role.init(dbRole, {
  sequelize: db,
  modelName: 't_role',
  timestamps: false,
  tableName: 't_roles',
});

Role.associate = (models) => {
  Role.belongsToMany(models.User, {
    through: { model: UserRole, unique: false },
    as: 'UserOfRoles',
    foreignKey: 'a_role',
    otherKey: 'a_user',
  });
};
```

**UserRole**

```js
class UserRole extends Sequelize.Model {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
}

const dbUserRole = {
  a_id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
  },
  a_role: {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: false,
    references: {
      model: Role,
      key: 'a_id',
    },
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  },
  a_user: {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: User,
      key: 'a_id',
    },
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  },
};

UserRole.init(dbUserRole, {
  sequelize: db,
  modelName: 't_user_role',
  timestamps: false,
  tableName: 't_user_role',
});
```

All associations are being invoked in my models `index.js`

**Models**

```js
import User from './User';
import UserRole from './UserRole';
import Role from './Role';

const models = {
  User,
  Role,
  UserRole,
};

Object.keys(models).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (models[modelName].associate) {
    models[modelName].associate(models);
  }
});

export default models;
```

**With that said, now the issue.**

I'm trying to query the `User` table and retrieve an user and, using `include`, also the `roles` associated to the user. But for some reason all the results I get are without the user's role.

**The query I'm using**

```js
const result = await User.findAll({
  where: {
    a_id: 1, // For simplicity
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Role, // The Role model class
      as: 'roles',
      attributes: ['a_role'],
      through: {
        attributes: [],
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

This query returns me the following object parsed as a JSON (even if I do not parse it, the `roles` key is not present in the plain sequelize response object):

```js
[
  {
    "a_id": 1,
    "a_date_created": "2020-05-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "a_first_name": "Thiago",
    "a_last_name": "moreira",
    "a_email": "thiago@mail.com",
    "a_password": "encrypted stuff",
    "a_birthday": "1991-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "a_is_active": true
  }
]
```

**The query that Sequelize outputs**

```sql
SELECT "t_user"."a_id",
    "t_user"."a_date_created",
    "t_user"."a_first_name",
    "t_user"."a_last_name",
    "t_user"."a_email",
    "t_user"."a_password",
    "t_user"."a_birthday",
    "t_user"."a_is_active",
    "roles"."a_id" AS "roles.a_id",
    "roles"."a_role" AS "roles.a_role",
    "roles->t_user_role"."a_id" AS "roles.t_user_role.a_id",
    "roles->t_user_role"."a_role" AS "roles.t_user_role.a_role",
    "roles->t_user_role"."a_user" AS "roles.t_user_role.a_user"
FROM "t_users" AS "t_user"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "t_user_role" AS "roles->t_user_role"
        INNER JOIN "t_roles" AS "roles" ON "roles"."a_id" = "roles->t_user_role"."a_role"
    )
    ON "t_user"."a_id" = "roles->t_user_role"."a_user";
```

(This is the `raw query` and works fine when I use it in `Postgres`)

According to my readings around the internet, the `findAll` method, when provided with an `include`, should be able also to return the association's data. To make everything a bit more weird, there are two scenarios where I'm able to retrieve the user's role (but if I understood the documentation correctly, those "workarounds" should not be necessary).

**First Scenario**

```js
const result = await User.findAll({
  where: {
    a_id: 1,
  },
  raw: true, // here is the difference from the previous approach
  nest: true, // here is the difference from the previous approach
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Role,
      as: 'roles',
      attributes: ['a_role'],
      through: {
        attributes: [],
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

**It returns**

```js
[
  {
    "a_id": 1,
    "a_date_created": "2020-05-24",
    "a_first_name": "Thiago",
    "a_last_name": "moreira",
    "a_email": "thiago@mail.com",
    "a_password": "encrypted stuff",
    "a_birthday": "1991-09-04",
    "a_is_active": true,
    "roles": {
      "a_role": "admin",
      "t_user_role": {
        "a_id": 1,
        "a_role": "1",
        "a_user": "1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Second scenario**

```js
const result = await User.findAll({
  where: {
    a_id: 1,
  },
});

// Here I get the first instance of the findAll return and
// use the getRoles function generated automatically by the
// Sequelize association.
JSON.stringify(await result[0].getRoles(), null, 2);
```

It returns

```js
[
  {
    "a_id": 1,
    "a_role": "admin"
  }
]
```

(Using that approach I would need to merge this result with the `User` instance).

What I still do not manage to understand is that, because of those two scenarios, the associated data seems to be present but for some reason it's not being returned using the "common" approach (which almost every Sequelize tutorial seems to use).

I'm sorry for the HUGE question but, as this topic is driving me crazy, I wanted to provide all the necessary context.

Comment: Can you remove `through: {
        attributes: [],
      },` and `attributes: ['a_role']` from the original query and check a result?

Comment: @Anatoly I did it and got the same result. What is also interesting is that if I paste the all the queries that Sequelizes outputs in my Terminal into `postgres` it also returns the `users` table **joined** with the `roles` table.

Comment: did you try to get plain objects like this (after the first query): `const plainResult = result.map(x => x.get({ plain: true }))`?

Comment: Hey @Anatoly, first of all thanks for sharing my struggle. I tried that and the result was unfortunately the same. I edit my question to include the `SQL Query` that Sequelize outputs in my Terminal. Maybe it can somehow help.

Comment: can you try to use `duplicating` option in `include` and look at SQL and sequelize query result?